# KIVY PYTHON how can i create text input submit button? instead of user pressing enter you have to press a button

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i want to prevent user from accidentaly pressing enter so instead i want "submit button" that will work as on_text_validation

```
TextInput:
    id: text_input_1
    size_hint: None, 1
    width: "100dp"
    text: "foo"
    multiline: False
    on_text_validate: root.on_text_validate(self)


Label:
    text: root.label_3

Button:
    on_click: text_input_1.submit  # # # # # # why doesnt this work?
```

i tried looking for button property that could work as enter press for  text input

i want it to work like that for multiline text.